# Briefly Drive Permanent Electromagnet

Tags: boost, electromagnet

I need to drive a 12VDC/1.2A permanent Electromagnet for 2 seconds (to release object).
Will the attached circuit be able to do that or do I need something else?
Thank you
[image: Circuit overview][image: Circuit Specific]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npy3w.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/alPLl.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3JYL.jpg

Comment: I suggest you embed those diagrams into your question (use the image attach tool), few people are going to follow the links.

Comment: Permanent magnet & electromagnet I understand, but could you please clarify a "permanent electromagnet".

Comment: The permanent Electromagnet is a electromagnet with a permanent magnet attached in center.  It attracts when power is off but when EM is energized it makes an exact opposite field to counter permanent magnet which "releases attached magnetic object.

Comment: @kevers - Hi, This question is effectively an update to your [previous one](/questions/610823). Please edit *that* question to include the images. You already linked to them in a comment there, but you *must* edit that question & please add the actual images (use Ctrl+G when editing), not just add links to them. Also, there are unanswered points in comments there, which you need to respond to by editing the question and supplying that information. Part of the "Stack Exchange approach" is that you should edit a question to improve it, not ask a new question if you are just adding info. Thanks